# How to expand to Labels having height in ratio 2:1?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uilabel

I'm new to xcode storyboard. I have a viewcontroller that contain two label of same width, but `label 1` is 80px in height and `label 2` is 40px in height.

I want those two labels to auto expand in height depending on whether they are displayed in horizontal or vertical size class, but I want `label 1` and `label 2` to keep their height ratio of `2:1`.

I know the steps to take if I wan't both labels to be the same height (control drag from one label to another, click equal height, and go to size inspector and set their content hugging priority to 200) , but I don't know the steps to take when I want the labels' height ratio to be `2:1` and to auto expand in height depending on whether it is displayed horizontally or vertically.

[image]

I want the two labels to expand, not the numbers below the labels

Comment: Aspect ratio *is* an auto layout attribute if you didn't know.

Comment: "I want those two labels to auto expand in height depending on whether they are displayed in horizontal or vertical size class" Unclear what you're asking for. What should their heights be? What does "auto expand in height" mean? Expand why?

Comment: @matt I want the ratio between Label 1's height and label 2's height to be 2:1. For example, if the height of label 1 is 80, then label 2's height should be 40. If height of label 1 expanded to 100, then the label 2's height should be 50.

Comment: Ah, ok my answer won't help you then. You will need some code to calculate the relationship, probably in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: @LukeVanIn but still, thank you so much for the suggestion!

Comment: "If height of label 1 expanded to 100," But what I'm asking you is, why would it do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want label 1 to be twice the height of label 2, then <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from label 1 to label 2 and select *Equal Heights* from the pop-up menu.  Then find this constraint in the *Document Outline* and edit it in the *Attributes Inspector* on the right.  Change the **multiplier** to `2`.

[image: Xcode demo of 2X height]

If you pin the orange label to the top of the screen and pin the bottom of label 1 to the top of label 2 and pin the bottom of label 2 to the views below, then these two views will fill in the space and maintain their relative vertical sizes.

Comment: thank you so much! something so simple took me hours lol can't thank you enough! really appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

To set the aspect ratio, Ctrl+drag from one point to another on the same view. Enter the aspect ratio in the multiplier.

For auto sizing, set the number of lines in the label to 0. The label will expand in the direction without a constraint (or the direction with the lowest priority constraints).

E.g. if you want the label to expand vertically, leave off the bottom constraint. To expand horizontally, leave off the right constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this :-

Take two labels:-

[image]

Click on first Label and add the following constants:-

[image]

now your label1 will look like this:-

[image]

Click on second label and add the following constants :-

[image]

Now both of your label will look like this:-

[image]

Update the frames :-

[image]

And run your App:-

> In Landscape

[image]

> In Portrait

[image]

> **Note**: if you want to set them in there ratio you can do this 
>   [image]           [image]